# Encounter exception after upgrading from FOP1.0 to FOP2.4

Tags: java, xml, xsl-fo, apache-fop

With same XML and XSL-FO FOP1.0 works fine. But after upgrade to FOP2.4 ,

I can see below warning and exception when converting the xml to print doc for printing on the TCP/IP printer.

WARNING: The contents of fo:region-after on page 1 exceed the available area in the block-progression direction by 13483 millipoints. (No context info available)
Exception:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderMainReference(AbstractRenderer.java:527)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderBodyRegion(AbstractRenderer.java:433)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderRegionViewport(AbstractRenderer.java:380)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderPageAreas(AbstractRenderer.java:345)
        at org.apache.fop.render.java2d.Java2DRenderer.print(Java2DRenderer.java:1008)
        at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.printPage(RasterPrinterJob.java:2166)
        at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(RasterPrinterJob.java:1548)
        at sun.print.Win32PrintJob.pageableJob(Win32PrintJob.java:576)
        at sun.print.Win32PrintJob.print(Win32PrintJob.java:393)
        at PrinterHandler.print(PrinterHandler.java:65)
        at Test.main(Test.java:734)
```

This issue is not seen when used FOP 1.0. After upgrade to FOP2.0, I started observing this exception hence document doesn't get print. Refer the below code which i have used.

Additionally , I downloaded the FOP2.4 source and see the below snippets. So can any one suggest what shall i need to change in our code or in XSL-FO schema to make this work. Below API is from FOP2.4. I did compare with FOP1.0 and see lots of changes related pageindex.

from **AbstractRenderer.java** :

```
 '''

protected void renderMainReference(MainReference mainReference) {
               //Few sample code snippets from FOP where exception seen
               if (flow != null) {

                        // if direction is right to left, then end is left edge,
                        // else end is right edge (for top-bottom/bottom-top block
                        // progression directions)

                        // binding edge is on left edge for odd pages and
                        // on right edge for even pages

                        ** int pageIndex = currentPageViewport.getPageIndex(); ** 
                       //Crashes as currentPageViewport is null
                    //More codes are below 
        }
```

This below example is taken from apache fop-2.4-bin\fop-2.4\fop\examples\embedding\java\embedding\ . This program is combination of ExampleXML2FO.java and ExampleFO2JPSPrint.java . I am trying to print the doc to printer, but above nullpointerexception raised.Below is the complete code to reproduce this issue.

**projectteam.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectteam>
  <projectname>The Killer Application</projectname>
  <member>
    <name>John Doe</name>
    <function>lead</function>
    <email>jon.doe@killerapp.fun</email>
  </member>
</projectteam>
```

**projectteam2fo.xsl**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
      <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:param name="versionParam" select="'1.0'"/> 
      <!-- ========================= -->
      <!-- root element: projectteam -->
      <!-- ========================= -->
      <xsl:template match="projectteam">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
          <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simpleA4" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="2cm" margin-left="2cm" margin-right="2cm">
              <fo:region-body/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
          </fo:layout-master-set>
          <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simpleA4">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
              <fo:block font-size="16pt" font-weight="bold" space-after="5mm">Project: <xsl:value-of select="projectname"/>
              </fo:block>
              <fo:block font-size="12pt" space-after="5mm">Version <xsl:value-of select="$versionParam"/>
              </fo:block>
              <fo:block font-size="10pt">
                <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border-collapse="separate">
                  <fo:table-column column-width="4cm"/>
                  <fo:table-column column-width="4cm"/>
                  <fo:table-column column-width="5cm"/>
                  <fo:table-body>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="member"/>
                  </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
              </fo:block>
            </fo:flow>
          </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
      </xsl:template>
      <!-- ========================= -->
      <!-- child element: member     -->
      <!-- ========================= -->
      <xsl:template match="member">
        <fo:table-row>
          <xsl:if test="function = 'lead'">
            <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:if>
          <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block>
              <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            </fo:block>
          </fo:table-cell>
          </fo:table-row>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Test.java**

```
//Java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

//JAXP
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXResult;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintException;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent;
import org.apache.fop.apps.Fop;
import org.apache.fop.render.print.PageableRenderer;

/**
 * This class demonstrates the conversion of an XML file to an XSL-FO file
 * using JAXP (XSLT).
 */

public class Test {

    /**
     * Converts an XML file to an XSL-FO file using JAXP (XSLT).
     * @param xml the XML file
     * @param xslt the stylesheet file
     * @param fo the target XSL-FO file
     * @throws IOException In case of an I/O problem
     * @throws TransformerException In case of a XSL transformation problem
     */
    public void convertXML2FO(File xml, File xslt, File fo)
                throws IOException, TransformerException {

        //Setup output
        OutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(fo);
        try {
            //Setup XSLT
            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslt));

            //Setup input for XSLT transformation
            Source src = new StreamSource(xml);

            //Resulting SAX events (the generated FO) must be piped through to FOP
            Result res = new StreamResult(out);

            //Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing
            transformer.transform(src, res);
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
    public static void printFO(File fo)
            throws IOException, FOPException, TransformerException, PrintException {

         // configure fopFactory as desired
        final FopFactory FOP_FACTORY = FopFactory.newInstance(new File(".").toURI());
        //Set up a custom user agent so we can supply our own renderer instance
        FOUserAgent userAgent = FOP_FACTORY.newFOUserAgent();

        PageableRenderer renderer = new PageableRenderer(userAgent);
        userAgent.setRendererOverride(renderer);

        // Construct FOP with desired output format
        Fop fop = FOP_FACTORY.newFop(userAgent);

        // Setup JAXP using identity transformer
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(); // identity transformer

        // Setup input stream
        Source src = new StreamSource(fo);

        // Resulting SAX events (the generated FO) must be piped through to FOP
        Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

        // Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing
        transformer.transform(src, res);

        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(renderer, DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE, null);
        final PrintService printer = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
        final DocPrintJob printJob = printer.createPrintJob();
        printJob.addPrintJobListener(null);
        new PrinterHandler().print(doc);

    }

    /**
     * Main method.
     * @param args command-line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("FOP ExampleXML2FO\n");
            System.out.println("Preparing...");

            //Setup directories
            File baseDir = new File(".");
            File outDir = new File(baseDir, "out");
            outDir.mkdirs();

            //Setup input and output files
            File xmlfile = new File(baseDir, "xml/xml/projectteam.xml");
            File xsltfile = new File(baseDir, "xml/xslt/projectteam2fo.xsl");
            File fofile = new File(outDir, "ResultXML2FO.fo");

            System.out.println("Input: XML (" + xmlfile + ")");
            System.out.println("Stylesheet: " + xsltfile);
            System.out.println("Output: XSL-FO (" + fofile + ")");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Transforming...");

            Test app = new Test();
            app.convertXML2FO(xmlfile, xsltfile, fofile);
            printFO(fofile);
            System.out.println(fofile);
            System.out.println("Success!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

**PrintHandler.java**

```
/**
 * PrinterHandler.java
 */

import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.event.PrintJobEvent;
import javax.print.event.PrintJobListener;


import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * Class PrinterHandler sends a print job to the default printer and observes the printer register
 * itself to the printer to inspect the state of the printer.
 *
 */
public final class PrinterHandler implements PrintJobListener {

    /** Logger. */
    private final Logger mLogger = Logger.getLogger(PrinterHandler.class.getName());

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public PrinterHandler() {
    }

    /**
     * Print the data contained in the Doc object.
     * <p>
     * The default printer configured in the operating system is used. If no default printer is
     * found, the first printer in the list of configured printers is used.
     *
     * @param doc is a Doc object which contains the printable data.
     * @return true if successfully printed.
     */
    public boolean print( Doc doc) {
        boolean success = true;
        PrintService printer = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

        if (printer == null) {
            final PrintService[] allPrinters =
                PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(doc.getDocFlavor(), null);

            if (allPrinters.length > 0) {
                printer = allPrinters[0];
                mLogger.info(printer.getName());
            }
        }
        if (printer == null) {
            mLogger.info( "no Printer");

        } else {
            final DocPrintJob printJob = printer.createPrintJob();

            try {
                mLogger.info("Printing document on " + printer.getName() + ".");
                printJob.addPrintJobListener(this);
                printJob.print(doc, null);
            }  catch (final Exception e) {
                success = false;
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                mLogger.info("Detailed Print Problem");
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(e);
            } finally {
                printJob.removePrintJobListener(this);
            }
        }
        return success;
    }

    /**
     * Called to notify the client that data has been successfully transferred to the print
     * service, and the client may free local resources allocated for that data.
     *
     * @param pje the job generating this event.
     * @see javax.print.event.PrintJobListener
     */
    @Override
    public void printDataTransferCompleted(final PrintJobEvent pje) {
        mLogger.info("Print Data Transfer Completed: " + pje.getPrintJob());
    }

    /**
     * Called to notify the client that the job was canceled by a user or a program.
     *
     * @param pje the job generating this event.
     * @see javax.print.event.PrintJobListener
     */
    @Override
    public void printJobCanceled(final PrintJobEvent pje) {
        mLogger.info("Print Job Canceled : " + pje.getPrintJob());
    }

    /**
     * Called to notify the client that the job completed successfully.
     *
     * @param pje the job generating this event.
     * @see javax.print.event.PrintJobListener
     */
    @Override
    public void printJobCompleted(final PrintJobEvent pje) {
        mLogger.info( "Print Job Completed : " + pje.getPrintJob());
    }

    /**
     * Called to notify the client that the job failed to complete successfully and
     * will have to be resubmitted.
     *
     * @param pje the job generating this event.
     * @see javax.print.event.PrintJobListener
     */
    @Override
    public void printJobFailed(final PrintJobEvent pje) {
        mLogger.info( "Print Job Failed : " + pje.getPrintJob());

          }

    /**
     * Called to notify the client that no more events will be delivered.
     *
     * @param pje the job generating this event.
     * @see javax.print.event.PrintJobListener
     */
    @Override
    public void printJobNoMoreEvents(final PrintJobEvent pje) {
        mLogger.info( "Print Job No More Events: " + pje.getPrintJob());
    }

    /**
     * Called to notify the client that an error has occurred that the user might be able to fix.
     *
     * @param pje the job generating this event.
     * @see javax.print.event.PrintJobListener
     */
    @Override
    public void printJobRequiresAttention(final PrintJobEvent pje) {
        mLogger.info("Print Job Requires Attention : " + pje.getPrintJob());
    }
}
```

My suspect is that , there might be some schema changes require in XSL-FO. But I am not able to figure out the actual reason of this issue.

Looking for you expert opinion on this to resolve this issue.Thank you!

Comment: FOP 2.5 was released in the last week.  Are you able to try your code and document with FOP 2.5?

Comment: I think the warning and the NullPointerException may be unrelated and refer to different causes. The warning just tells you that the content in the page footer is taller than the available space (but it should appear in the output anyway). The NullPointerException is a serious error encountered by FOP while processing your file.  I suggest adding to the question a minimal FO file showing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the information!

Comment: Added complete program with  minimal xml and FO, showing this problem.

Comment: Tony, as suggested, I used FOP2.5 libs, and encounter the same exception as described in the problem.